# Identify this old E27 5W 230V short lightbulb

Tags: light-fixture, the-netherlands

I've recently discovered (under a ceiling that I took off) and old wall-mounted lamp. It has a curious lightbulb which I failed to identify so far. The lightbulb works right now (gives a beautiful "retro" glow), but should it ever die, I'd like to know if there's an option for a replacement. The issue is that the bulb is very short - around 15 mm - to fit the small housing of the lamp.

The lightbulb is 5W, has an E27 thread. Location is Netherlands (230 V).

I would appreciate help with identifying this lightbulb - or information on similar bulb types that would fit the housing - so that I can search for replacement options.

[image: bulb]
[image: bulb]
[image: bulb]

Comment: Check bulbs made for ovens - often short etc

Comment: @SolarMike But ovens mostly have E14 threads, AFAIK.

Comment: Closest I've seen is a pygmy indicator/pilot bulb https://www.uklightbulbs.co.uk/low-voltage-light-bulbs-t-type-miniature-pygmy-bulbs-e10-e14-e12-mcc-ba9s/2810-pygmy-light-bulb-240-volts-15-watts-es-tubular.html

Comment: That retro thing is a genuine incandescent bulb, which makes light by making heat.  Basically it's an electric campfire.  It won't last long; it should go to the lightbulb museum while it still can!

Comment: Quite a bit longer and probably brighter but [these](https://www.ultraleds.co.uk/pygmy-t28-led-crown-filament-bulb-lamp-e27-edison-screw-2w-dimmable.html) are at least LED.

Answer (score 2):

The nearest I can find in size and wattage is a Bulbrite Industries, Inc. E26/E27 7.5 watt "25G12/CL-220" at this website:

https://bulbman.com/globe/3391-25g12-cl-220.html (I don't know anything about bulbman.com)

It looks like a 220v decorative bulb. I have not been able to find a direct replacement.

Based upon the filament supports, it looks like a very long-lasting bulb design. If the bulb is rated for 230v and is being used in a 220v environment, it will last roughly twice as long as its rating.

If the color doesn't matter, you could use a 7.5 watt S11 sign light bulb with an E26 base. Unknown availability in EU.

Or you could go with any number of LED replacements.

This was a challenge to find a relatively close match in the US.